# How to set specifications for multiple block diagrams using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, circuitikz, circuits

I have the code for a very simple open loop diagram and a closed loop diagram

[image]

The output line for the feedback loop under Y(s) is too short, I would like to expand it by 1 cm. However if I change the line in Tikz set 
from

```
output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
```

to

```
output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=2cm},
```

Then the top figure change as well, so now the output line for the open loop diagram is now too long.

[image]

How do I declare multiple Tikz set for each diagram I have in Tikz? i.e. different specifications for different diagrams. Or is there another solution that I can use locally for each diagram?

Please help and may god save america.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {$U(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of input] (controller) {$C(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of controller] (plant) {$G(s)$};
            \node [output, right=of plant] (output) {};
            \draw [->] (input) -- node {$U(s)$} (controller);
            \draw [->] (controller) -- (plant);
            \draw [->] (plant) -- node [name = y] {$Y(s)$} (output);
            \end{tikzpicture}  
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {};
            \node [sum, right=of input] (sum) {};
            \node [block, right=of sum] (controller) {$C(s)$};
            \node [block, right=2 of controller] (plant) {$G(s)$};
            \node [output, right=of plant] (output) {};
            \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$U(s)$} (sum);
            \draw [->] (sum) -- node {} (controller);
            \draw [->] (controller) -- node {} (plant);
            \draw [->] (plant) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
            \draw [->] (y) -- ++ (0,-2) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (sum);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{TikzPicture}\label{fig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the style of `output` when and wherever `\tikset` can be issued (which is pretty much anywhere). So if you say, between the two `tikzpicture`s: `\tikzset{output/.style={node distance=2cm}}` it will change from there afterwards. You can also use the optional part of the `tikzpicture` to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti*k*Z styles can be created/changed in the middle of the document using either `\tikzset` or even through the optional argument of **`tikzpicture`** the same way it was created beforehand.

So if you want the *just* the second picture to have a `node distance` of `2cm`, you can just change the `output` style *in* that picture using either `\tikzset` inside the **`tikzpicture`** environment or the optional part of the Environment, those are both local changes.

If you want to change the setting of `output` globally, then use `\tikzset` outside of the **`tikzpicture`**, then all pictures after issuing `\tikzset` will inherit the style settings.

See this MWE as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
                    minimum height=1cm,
                    minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {$U(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of input] (controller) {$C(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of controller] (plant) {$G(s)$};
            \node [output, right=of plant] (output) {};
            \draw [->] (input) -- node {$U(s)$} (controller);
            \draw [->] (controller) -- (plant);
            \draw [->] (plant) -- node [name = y] {$Y(s)$} (output);
            \end{tikzpicture}

%           \tikzset{output/.style = {node distance=2cm}} %<< global change (uncomment to see the difference)

            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
                                node distance=1cm,
                                >=latex',
                                output/.style = {node distance=2cm}] % << local change
            \tikzset{output/.style = {node distance=2cm}} %<< also local change
            \node [input, name=input] {};
            \node [sum, right=of input] (sum) {};
            \node [block, right=of sum] (controller) {$C(s)$};
            \node [block, right=2 of controller] (plant) {$G(s)$};
            \node [output, right=of plant] (output) {};
            \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$U(s)$} (sum);
            \draw [->] (sum) -- node {} (controller);
            \draw [->] (controller) -- node {} (plant);
            \draw [->] (plant) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
            \draw [->] (y) -- ++ (0,-2) -| node [pos=0.99] {$-$} (sum);
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,>=latex']
            \node [input, name=input] {$U(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of input] (controller) {$C(s)$};
            \node [block, right=of controller] (plant) {$G(s)$};
            \node [output, right=of plant] (output) {};
            \draw [->] (input) -- node {$U(s)$} (controller);
            \draw [->] (controller) -- (plant);
            \draw [->] (plant) -- node [name = y] {$Y(s)$} (output);
            \end{tikzpicture} 
        \end{center}
        \caption{TikzPicture}\label{fig}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```